# ¿Como puedo solucionar este problema en un job de sql server?

Tags: sql-server, jobs

Estuve investigando pero no encuentro solución a este problema en un Job que tengo en SQL server básicamente me esta reclamando que se esta duplicando un dato en el insert a la tabla

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cómo puedo solucionar este problema?

Comment: Saludos @EduAraneda, primero que nada seria mucho mejor si pusieras el error en formato de texto y segundo según veo el error es porque estas ingresando una dato repetido en la llave, como recomendación siempre traduce primero el error ya que muchas veces verás que en este caso es muy claro, es necesario más información para ayudarte de manera más específica. ;)

Comment: SOlución: no insertes datos duplicados en las tablas que validan campos con restricciones de unicidad.

Comment: Para solucionar el problema, corrige el código que inserta una llave primaria que ya existe en la tabla. Después de eso, todo funcionará bien. ;) No olvides leer [ask].